# Swift : How to sort alphabetically but with letters first

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, realm

i have a Realm results list:

```
subsList = RealmDB.objects(Downloads).filter("isActive = true").sorted("name", ascending: true)
```

And it display the results ordered, but the first results are "(item 1)" or 1-item, then comes A-item, B-item etc...

How can i sort it in a ways that A-item, B-item etc.. come first and (item 1), 1-item display at the end?

note: for those who don't know realm, it can take a NSPredicate for sorting

Thanks guys

EDIT:
Following the comments, I'm getting

```
-chloro
(+-)-1,2,3-octa
(amino)
1-propanol
acetone
benzin
dinoterb
TNT
```

And i need

```
acetone
benzin
dinoterb
TNT
-chloro
(+-)-1,2,3-octa
(amino)
1-propanol
```

Comment: Show some actual strings, your desired sort order, and what you're getting instead. I have no idea what. You mean by 1-item, A-item, etc.

Comment: I edited my answer, but what i do not understand is why do you need the "-" before the "(". alphabetically the "(" goes first

Comment: I don't, it was just some random order. What i need first it's A, B ,C etc. the symbols order it's not relevant, they only need to be at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example, fix the code to make it look better.

```
var arr = ["-chloro", "(+-)-1,2,3-octa", "(amino)", "1-propanol", "acetone", "benzin","dinoterb","TNT"]

func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0,     length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}


arr.sort { (s1, s2) -> Bool in
    let matched = matches(for: "[0-9,\\(,\\-]", in: s1)
    let matched2 = matches(for: "[0-9\\(,\\-]", in: s2)
    if matched.isEmpty && matched2.isEmpty {
        return s1.lowercased() < s2.lowercased()
    } else if matched.isEmpty && !matched2.isEmpty {
        return true
    } else if !matched.isEmpty && matched2.isEmpty {
        return false
    } else {
        return matched.first! < matched2.first!
    }
}
```

result -> ["acetone", "benzin", "dinoterb", "TNT", "(+-)-1,2,3-octa", "(amino)", "-chloro", "1-propanol"]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try it